# Python 2 Tornado asychronous method

Tags: python-2.7, tornado

I have to use Python 2 to make asynchronous calls.

I'm using Tornado to accomplish this but if there is a better tool I can change tools.

The following code runs my `sleep 2 && echo hi` command asynchronously in the background

```
from tornado import gen
import subprocess
import time

@gen.coroutine
def longProcess():
    bashCommand = "sleep 5 && echo hi"
    process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output, error = process.communicate()

    yield output

futures = [longProcess() for x in range(0, 5)]

while True:
    if all(x.done() == True for x in futures):
        break
    time.sleep(1)

print('All futures resolved')
```

The problem is that `x.done()` is returning `True` for all futures before my bash command is finished.

How can I turn `process.communicate()` into a future (Only done once the keyword "hi" is available) so that I can wait on all the futures to be done and get then get the output from the futures?

Answer (score 0):

Use Tornado's own [`process.Subprocess`](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/process.html#tornado.process.Subprocess) class which is a wrapper around stdlib's `subprocess.Popen`.

Example:

```
from tornado import process

@gen.coroutine
def longProcess():
    bashCommand = "sleep 5 && echo hi"

    proc = process.Subprocess(bashCommand.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

    yield proc.wait_for_exit() # `wait_for_exit` returns a future 
                               # which you can yield. Basically, it means
                               # you can wait for the process to complete
                               # without blocking the server

    return proc.stdout.read() # return the result of the process

    # for Python 2:
    # you can't return from a generator
    # instead use this:
    # raise gen.Return(proc.stdout.read())
```

You don't need the `while` loop. You can move that code inside some other coroutine and yield the list of `futures`. Like this:

```
@gen.coroutine
def main():
    futures = [longProcess() for x in range(0, 5)]

    results = yield futures # this coroutine will not move further 
                            # until every future in the list 
                            # `futures` is resolved

    for result in results:
        print(result)

    print('All futures resolved')
```

---

As a side note, don't use `time.sleep`. It will block the whole server. Instead use the asynchronous equivalent [`gen.sleep`](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/gen.html#tornado.gen.sleep) - `yield gen.sleep(1)`

Comment: Using that code I get: `return proc.stdout.read() # return the result of the process
SyntaxError: 'return' with argument inside generator`

Comment: @ClickThisNick Ah, you must be using Python 2. In place of the `return` statement, you'll need to use -- [`raise gen.Return(proc.stdout.read())`](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/gen.html#tornado.gen.Return)

Comment: That still gives an error `*** AttributeError: 'Subprocess' object has no attribute 'wait_for_exit'`. Since I'm using Python2 I have to use tornado 4, perhaps this works with tornado 5 (Which doesn't work with Python 2)

Comment: @ClickThisNick `wait_for_exit` was added in Tornado 4.2. BTW, Tornado 5 also supports Python 2.